# FlatList inside a FlatList does not scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-ui-kitten

Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@mr3mo/snack-flatlist

I am trying to render a screen where it will show various graphs and one or more tables. The screen needs to be scrollable.

I used a ScrollView for the parent scroll before but this was giving me a warning as it is not a good practice to include FlatLists inside a ScrollView due to performance reasons.

So I created this VirtualizedView which is a FlatList where all the components of my screen are rendered in the ListHeaderComponent.

Unfortunately this causes my child FlatList to not be scrollable.

I have tried many things, including setting a maxHeight, flexGrow etc. without much luck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please check your snack it's having some error.

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I have fixed the snack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem.

The trick is to wrap the List inside a `ScrollView` component and wrap the whole screen component inside the `VirtualizedVIew` component I shared in the snack.

This is what my LogsScreen.jsx file looks like:

```
import { VirtualizedView } from "../components";
...
return (
  <View>
    <VirtualizedView>
      ...
    <ScrollView>
      <FlatList>
      ...
      </FlatList>
    </ScrollView>
    </VirtualizedView>
   </View>
)

Inside VirtualizedView.jsx:

import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, View } from 'react-native';

export default function VirtualizedView(props) {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={[]}
      ListEmptyComponent={null}
      keyExtractor={() => "dummy"}
      renderItem={null}
      ListHeaderComponent={() => (
        <>{props.children}</>
      )}
      ListFooterComponent={<View style={{height: 20}}/>}
    />
  );
}
```